# Craft cms[4.x]: Frontend Site broke after performing a feed with feed me

Tags: php, craft4, graphql

On our last data migration from wordpress i import through feed me all the data but the postDates.

31-08-2023 11:12 I imported a csv file in feed me with all the posts content including the postDates which it was successful.

I tried first on our staging environment and everything worked fine.
So I went to production and I noticed, in this version, feed me was not installed. So I installed it back, following on dashboard instructions steps.
Performed the import with feed me (updating just the postDates) for every post (blog section) realising the frontend site went  to the Server error page

Screenshot:
https://github.com/craftcms/cms/assets/58745451/5528ba7f-c86d-4ea3-91ce-f1b45b20130c

We were getting an undefined entry error on the frontend. Which it didn't make sense as it was working till the feed, or the composer update, or the db update. We have a Craft 4, Nuxt 2 (^2.15.8) app running.

We were getting a Graphql error on the console:

```
“errors”: [
        {
            “message”: “Something went wrong when processing the GraphQL query.”
        }
    ]
}
```

Screenshot:
https://github.com/craftcms/cms/assets/58745451/618a1157-9359-486d-9af2-ca998e7097c5

That fragment was appearing everywhere and throwing an error.

yarn packages:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/gtm": "^2.4.0",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.5",
    "@nuxtjs/robots": "^2.5.0",
    "@nuxtjs/sitemap": "^2.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.19.3",
    "fake-tag": "^2.0.0",
    "graphql": "^15.4.0",
    "gsap": "npm:@gsap/member",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "nuxt-intercom": "^1.1.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-horizontal": "^0.8.12",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.16.3",
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^1.21.7",
    "@graphql-codegen/fragment-matcher": "^2.0.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/introspection": "^1.18.2",
    "@nuxt/image": "^0.7.1",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^8.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.2",
    "dashjs": "^4.7.0",
    "eslint": "^8.4.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.2.0",
    "graphql-cli": "4.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "sass-loader": "10",
    "vue-observe-visibility": "^1.0.0"
  }
```

After a few hours, we got it fixed by moving the inline graphql fragments from the top of the query to the bottom :

```
export const containerQuery = gql`
 ${entryBlocks}  (from here)
 ${parent}  (from here)
  query containerQuery($slug: [String], $level: Int, $id: [QueryArgument]) {
    entry(section: "pageContainer", slug: $slug, level: $level, id: $id) {
      level
      slug
      id
      title
      typeHandle
      ...parent
      ...entryBlocks
      children {
    ...
(to here)`
```

We managed to fix it, but it would be nice to know what exactly happened.

Here are the php error logs for that day:

```
- 10:33(1) - 11:22 (10) - 14:08 (2) > 13 instances of this one: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table ‘guestxm_production.sites’ doesn’t exist in /home/forge/craft.guestxm.com/cms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php:1302

 - ReflectionException: Class “yii\web\JsonResponseFormatter” does not exist
Error: Class “yii\di\NotInstantiableException” not found in /home/forge/craft.guestxm.com/cms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:509

 - 14:18 (9) > craft\errors\SiteNotFoundException: No sites exist in /home/forge/craft.guestxm.com/cms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Request.php:1469
```

If you need the full detailed version of any of the logs please let me know

Some help will be appreciated.

#### Craft CMS version

4.5.3

#### PHP version

8.1.5

#### Operating system and version

Mac Ventura 13.1 (22C65)

#### Database type and version

mysql 8.0.21

#### Image driver and version

*No response*

#### Installed plugins and versions

```
"craftcms/aws-s3": "2.0.3",
"craftcms/cms": "^4.0.0-beta.4",
"craftcms/feed-me": "5.2.0",
"craftcms/redactor": "3.0.4",
"nystudio107/craft-autocomplete": "^1.0.0",
"nystudio107/craft-imageoptimize": "4.0.5",
"nystudio107/craft-retour": "4.1.12",
"nystudio107/craft-seomatic": "4.0.28",
"verbb/formie": "2.0.32",
"vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.4.0",
"yiisoft/yii2-redis": "^2.0.6"
```